# webpack-dev-server fails to run

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am new to reactjs and webpack. So I am trying the following awesome video to install webpack and dev server:

[Setup Workspace with Webpack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uextYhQGP6k&t=407s)

and here is the sample project I am working on:
[project](https://github.com/mschwarzmueller/reactjs-basics)

I did everything step by step and now when I run npm start I get the following error:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-    cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v7.2.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle reactjs-basics@1.0.0~prestart: reactjs-basics@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle reactjs-basics@1.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart,   continuing
7 info lifecycle reactjs-basics@1.0.0~start: reactjs-basics@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle reactjs-basics@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
 9 verbose lifecycle reactjs-basics@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program     Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\tj\reactjs-basics\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32  ;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\CCM;C:\WINDOWS\CCM;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;C:\Users\hminaee\AppData\Roaming\npm
 10 verbose lifecycle reactjs-basics@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\tj\reactjs-basics
11 silly lifecycle reactjs-basics@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run build' ]
12 silly lifecycle reactjs-basics@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle reactjs-basics@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: reactjs-basics@1.0.0 start: `npm run build`
 14 verbose stack Exit status 1
 14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)
 14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
 14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
 14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
 14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
 14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
 14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:885:16)
 14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
 15 verbose pkgid reactjs-basics@1.0.0
 16 verbose cwd C:\tj\reactjs-basics
 17 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
 18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
 19 error node v7.2.1
 20 error npm  v3.10.10
 21 error code ELIFECYCLE
 22 error reactjs-basics@1.0.0 start: `npm run build`
 22 error Exit status 1
 23 error Failed at the reactjs-basics@1.0.0 start script 'npm run build'.
 23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
 23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the reactjs-basics package,
  23 error not with npm itself.
  23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
  23 error     npm run build
  23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
  23 error     npm bugs reactjs-basics
  23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
  23 error     npm owner ls reactjs-basics
   23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
   24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Also here is my package.json file:

```
  {
  "name": "reactjs-basics",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "index.js",
   "scripts": {
   "start": "npm run build",
   "build": "webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-     server --content-base src/ --inline --hot --port 3003",
  "build:prod": "webpack -p && cp src/index.html dist/index.html"
   },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
   "react": "^15.4.1",
   "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
   "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
    },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.20.0",
   "babel-loader": "^6.2.9",
   "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.18.0",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
 }
```

I checked the web and I saw many solution regarding to the port. So I change the port to an open port like this : --port 3003 but still webpack-dev-server does not work. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: Is that big space between 'webpack-dev-' and 'server' a typo? Also do  you have a webpack config file?

Comment: Yes it is a typo also I do have webpack config file